# Installing composer in a docker image

Tags: php, linux, docker, composer-php

So i tried many ways, but this one seems the most legit way of installing composer in a docker image :

https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/

Now when im trying to do the "same", i'm getting:

`latest: Pulling from composer/composer
Status: Image is up to date for composer/composer:latest
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app`

When im running it:
`docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer/composer install`
Even if i change the /app route to /var/www, i still get the same error that it cant find the composer.json in /app.

How do i make it so that it looks in the directory where i need the composer? I dont understand the `$(pwd)` part but tried it several ways.. I dont have any volumes created as im using php from tutum/lamp. 
I am also not using docker-compose so if possible, tell me some way of doing it without docker compose.

Can provide more details if needed.

**EDIT**

Could it be something regarding the volumes? Currently i have the `composer.json` file in `/var/protobuf` and i use this command: `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/protobuf composer/composer install` to tell it about the directory of the json file, but it still keeps looking in `/app`, maybe i need to create volumes?

Comment: In the step two of the docs it says: `2.Create a composer.json defining your dependencies`....

Comment: pwd stands for *print working directory* (or similar), so you're basically mounting current directory as /app inside container. Are you sure composer.json is present in current directory and is not misspelled?

Comment: @Etki the current code is `docker run -v $(pwd):/var/protobuf composer/composer install` I still get the error that its looking in /app ..

In the /var/protobuf i have the composer.json @Hackerman

Comment: That's because container working directory is still `/app`. I'd stick with it, since it doesn't matter where it ends inside container.